# Vim isn't indenting Python properly -- Flask app, Trisquel Mini GNU/Linux, lxterminal

Tags: python, linux, vim, flask

I'm going through [Miguel Ginberg's Flask Mega-Tutorial](https://blog.miguelgrinberg.com/post/the-flask-mega-tutorial-part-v-user-logins). The file I'm working on that isn't indenting properly is microblog/app/views.py, and it looks like this:

```
from flask import render_template, flash, redirect, session, url_for, request, g
from flask_login import login_user, logout_user, current_user, login_required
from app import app, db, lm, oid
from .forms import LoginForm
from .models import User

@app.route('/')
@app.route('/index')
def index():
    user = {'nickname': 'Phaed'}
    posts = [
            {   
                'author': {'nickname': 'John'},
                'body': 'Beautiful day in Portland!'
            },
            {   
                'author': {'nickname': 'Susan'},
                'body': 'The Avengers movie was so cool!'
            }
    ]
    return render_template('index.html',
                           title='Home',
                           user=user,
                           posts=posts)

@app.route('/login', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
@oid.loginhandler
def login():
    if g.user is not None and g.user.is_authenticated:
        return redirect(url_for('index'))
    form = LoginForm()
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        session['remember_me'] = form.remember_me.data
        return oid.try_login(form.openid.data, ask_for=['nickname', 'email'])
    return render_template('login.html',
                           title='Sign In',
                           form=form,
                           providers=app.config['OPENID_PROVIDERS'])

@lm.user_loader
def load_user(id):
    return User.query.get(int(id))
```

When I execute gg=G on this file, my indentation gets messed up. Brackets and curlies for my example data initialization statements, the render_template arguments, @app.route('/login', ...), and @lm.user_loader; they all get messed up:

```
from flask import render_template, flash, redirect, session, url_for, request, g
from flask_login import login_user, logout_user, current_user, login_required
from app import app, db, lm, oid
from .forms import LoginForm
from .models import User

@app.route('/')
@app.route('/index')
def index():
    user = {'nickname': 'Phaed'}
    posts = [
            {   
                'author': {'nickname': 'John'},
                'body': 'Beautiful day in Portland!'
                },
            {   
                'author': {'nickname': 'Susan'},
                'body': 'The Avengers movie was so cool!'
                }
            ]
    return render_template('index.html',
                title='Home',
                user=user,
                posts=posts)

    @app.route('/login', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
@oid.loginhandler
def login():
    if g.user is not None and g.user.is_authenticated:
        return redirect(url_for('index'))
    form = LoginForm()
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        session['remember_me'] = form.remember_me.data
        return oid.try_login(form.openid.data, ask_for=['nickname', 'email'])
    return render_template('login.html',
            title='Sign In',
            form=form,
            providers=app.config['OPENID_PROVIDERS'])

    @lm.user_loader
def load_user(id):
    return User.query.get(int(id))
```

Why is this? I figure it must be .vimrc settings, but after hours of reading and tweaking and no luck, I posted here. The indentation rules in my .vimrc:

```
set autoindent
set smartindent
filetype plugin indent on
set tabstop=4
set softtabstop=4
set expandtab
set shiftwidth=4
```

Any help is greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: In the future, please post `vim` Qs to http://vi.stackexchange.com . Glad you found a solution.

Comment: @shellter vim questions aren't off-topic for SO.

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind! Would still be curious how to solve this without using a package manager, but I started using Vundle to try out this PEP8 indentation package, and -voila-.

https://github.com/Vimjas/vim-python-pep8-indent

Cheers!